# Tool for logs analysis (filtering / grouping / multi thread analysis)

Tags: java, multithreading

I didn't have any experience in the .log files parsing/filtering/grouping.

There is a directory that contains multiple log files. The number of files can be big and the number of lines in one log can be also big. Each log record contains at least time, username and custom message.

Tool should scan directory for log files, read log files and filter log records that conform to user input and produce output given below.

As a ***input parameters*** I have next:

***Filter parameters***  (at least one should be specified)

- Username
- Time period
- Pattern for custom message

***Grouping parameters*** (at least one should be specified)

- Username
- Time unit (e.g. 1 hour, 1 day, 1 month)

***Other parameters -***

- Count of threads used to process files. Each file can be processed in separate thread. (default=1)
- Path or filename to output file

That is everything that user might be entered as a input parameters for filtering/grouping / etc.

As the ***output*** I should have next:

- Single file with all filtered log record.
- Print aggregate statistics (Count of records grouped by grouping input parameters)

***Can you suggest right way to build that app.*** Or maybe you have any other advises about the structure for this app.

1. How to organize filtering and grouping, should I create some temp file for filtering and after that use "grouping" for that temp file?
2. How to organize multi thread analysis according user input?

Should I use any parser before filtering procedure?

Comment: Please explain the part of your question "multi thread analysis". What kind of threads are you thinking of?

Comment: Did you really need to programm an application? Have you looked for existing tools? This is a common task and there are many good tools on the market. Maybe unix command line tools "grep" and "awk" could do the job.

Comment: About multi thread analysis, according the input parameters user can input any number of threads for process all files, and in that case  I need to use multithreading for processed all files in folder more efficiency.

Comment: I also know about the existing tools, this job is for educational purposes.

Comment: Are you allowed to put them into a (SQL)DB? Then you have all that SQL gives you for sorting, grouping, filtering ...

Comment: Yes, It's also be Ok. But as I read before for the big numbers of files and big files it's more slowly than do that staff by hand isn't is?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on centralize log management tools like [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) and [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/). So you can focus on main application logic.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, But as I wrote above I need a custom app.

Comment: Like joney_000 said, use something existing. Another option is logstash, elasticsearch and kibana which solves that for you.